# ScrollView content not filling in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I have a scrollview which content is a `VStack` containing a ForEach loop to create some Rows instead of a list. A List has some downsides like the dividers.

My Issue is that the Row is not filling the scrollview. I think the scrollview width is not filling the screen.

```
NavigationView {
        Toggle(isOn: $onlineStatus) {
            Text("Online Only")
        }.padding([.leading, .trailing], 15)

        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                ForEach(onlineStatus ? self.notes.filter { $0.dot == .green } : self.notes) { note in
                    NavigationButton(destination: Text("LOL")) {
                        CardRow(note: note)
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                            .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 3, x: 0, y: -0.01)
                    }.padding([.leading, .trailing, .top], 5)
                }.animation(self.onlineStatus ? .fluidSpring() : nil)
            }
        }.padding([.leading, .trailing])

        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Your documents"))
    }
```

This is giving me this result:

[image]

That's my CardRow:

```
struct CardRow: View {
var note: Note

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "writing.png")!)
            .padding(.leading, 10)

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Group {
                Text(note.message)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text(note.date)
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
            .foregroundColor(.black)
        }

        Spacer()
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Circle().foregroundColor(note.dot)
                .frame(width: 7, height: 7)
                .shadow(radius: 1)
                .padding(.trailing, 5)
            Spacer()
        }.padding(.top, 5)
    }
    .frame(height: 60)
    .background(Color(red: 237/255, green: 239/255, blue: 241/255))
}
```

}

Comment: I guess the issue is with your CardRow view. I replaced it with a simple Text element and it fills the screen.

Comment: Hmm. I've added the cardRow to the question

Comment: I had the same issue. The only thing that helped me was replace `ScrollView` with `List`...

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I don't want a list. It has ugly dividors

Comment: I know. Looking forward to some real answer... @jsbeginnerNodeJS

Comment: I found a solution. See in the comments of my accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the frame width of the RowView to UIScreen.main.bounds.width:
`.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)`

Comment: But then the row is getting over the screen. I want the width to be the scrollviews width

Comment: If I subtract that value the padding I gave the scrollview + its row it worked.

Comment: Not really a solution to the issue. More like a workaround imho → should not be accepted!

Comment: @LinusGeffarth what would u do instead?

Comment: This was super helpful. I was able to use this to work around the GeometryReader / AppStorage bug by taking UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.75, which gives me exactly what I need for my situation.

Answer (score 6):

Use `.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)` on the RowView or inside of it

Comment: Still the same.

Answer (score 5):

Best solution I found is to use GeometryReader to fill the ScrollView's contents to the outer view's width. And be sure to use a Spacer() in each row's HStack. This handles safe areas and rotation well.

```
struct Card : View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Header")
                    .font(.headline)
                Text("Description")
                    .font(.body)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.15), radius: 8, x: 0, y: 0)
    }
}

struct Home : View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                        Card()
                        Card()
                        Card()
                    }
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                }
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See resulting screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Great stuffs. Worked pretty well

Comment: Spacer() does the trick especially when the content of a cell is covering the one side of the cell i.e. left or right. So adding spacer() would take up the space after the content till the end of the space taken by parent

Comment: This really helped me out trying to get TextEditor views to render more dynamically within a VStack, within a ScrollView.