# VStack not filling screen width in ScrollView, does fill in List

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've created a scrollable list of images as follows:

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        ForEach(landmarks) { landmark in
            landmark.image(forSize: 200)
              // some modifiers...
    }
    .navigationBarTitle(Text(category.rawValue))
}
```

This is the UI this code produces:

[image]

Now, I'd like to get rid of the line separators that `List` creates. Therefor, I replaced `List` with `ScrollView`. This is what the preview then shows:

[image]

How do I fix this?

I've seen [this other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56514140/3397217), but the accepted answer doesn't actually solve the problem, but introduces a fixed width.

Comment: Have you tried `.relativeWidth(<#T##proportion: Length##Length#>)` on the scroll view?  You didn't post your code, so it's hard to tell if it will work.

Answer (score 7):

Found a full `SwiftUI` solution.

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ScrollView(alwaysBounceVertical: true) {
            VStack {
                // Your code
            }.frame(width: geometry.size.width)
        }
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

Comment: Leaving out `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` makes this a great solution. Although I'm not sure why it is this way. This solution also doesn't look like it's supposed to be implemented like this.

Comment: The key is `GeometryReader` to avoid using UIKit.

Comment: Any reason to avoid UIKit?

Comment: Dependence to UIKit

Comment: is there a way to load Image with Data without using UIImage? @FlorentMorin

Comment: UIImage is available for all platforms, including macOS via UIKit for macOS. But you can also use NSImage for macOS.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, apparently the scroll view uses the minimum size as possible.

You can add the .frame modifier to the content inside the stack and declare his width as the screen's width like this:

```
ContentInsideScrollView { ... }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
```

pay attention of the padding, your scroll view could extends over the screen's width.

Otherwise you can set your row with an infinity width:

```
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
```

Either-way, you have to work with the **.frame** modifier

Comment: Is that value bindable, or does it break when rotating the device?

Comment: I really don't know, a lot of APIs are still to be released. You have to make your tests. But I think that when you rotate your device the View should be redraw so you will get the new value

Comment: True, I was mostly asking for "future readers". And the added point about checking for the padding is also a good one. Using the screen width would probably collide with the safeAreaInsets in landscape mode on a iPhone X (which may or may not be intentional for a scrollView).

Comment: Hmm this does not affect the scroll view's layout at all for me... I have to wrap the `ForEach` in a `VStack` and then apply the `.frame(width: UIScreen...)` part to that, instead of the `ScrollView` itself.